# SQL COUNT of rows is different to Tableau Count of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-desktop

I have the below table which I created in Excel and imported into SQL Server. It contains the Orders a restaurant received during a seven week period on Doordash. Certain customers are "Dashpass" members, which is a monthly subscription for free delivery, they are denoted as "Yes" and customers who don't use Dashpass are denoted as "No".

I want to find the number of customers who were Dashpass members or not. I understand that I have to remove duplicate names, which I have done.

So Excel tells me there is 66 "No" and 66 "Yes" customers. Tableau also tells me the same thing. But SQL says that there is 67 "no" and 66 "yes" customers. It's counting one extra "no". Anyone know why?

**SQL Code used:**

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS Dashpass_Members, Dashpass
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME, Dashpass
    FROM DD_Customers
) AS DPMC
GROUP BY Dashpass
```

**Table**

| ORDER_ID | DATE | DAY | NAME | TYPE | DASHPASS | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49FDAF27 | 1/06/2022 | Wednesday | Andrew H | Delivery | No | 36 |
| 4965A11A | 1/06/2022 | Wednesday | Aabiskar B | Delivery | Yes | 25 |
| FFC58DCA | 1/06/2022 | Wednesday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 23.5 |
| 696EEE6C | 1/06/2022 | Wednesday | Chris P | Pickup | No | 21.5 |
| DD1B8F51 | 2/06/2022 | Thursday | Marco L | Pickup | No | 29 |
| 81B3D270 | 2/06/2022 | Thursday | Lili M | Pickup | No | 35 |
| 3801217D | 2/06/2022 | Thursday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 27 |
| 89FD504C | 3/06/2022 | Friday | Marco L | Pickup | No | 34.5 |
| 7AB78F00 | 3/06/2022 | Friday | Ann S | Delivery | Yes | 39.5 |
| A7404B6B | 3/06/2022 | Friday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| 40011768 | 4/06/2022 | Saturday | Puneet M | Pickup | No | 32.5 |
| 01F45C26 | 4/06/2022 | Saturday | Hayden K | Delivery | No | 28.5 |
| 80CB6345 | 4/06/2022 | Saturday | Ravi R | Delivery | Yes | 29 |
| 932827F4 | 5/06/2022 | Sunday | Priya S | Delivery | No | 20 |
| ADCC8FA7 | 5/06/2022 | Sunday | Nina Z | Delivery | No | 25.5 |
| CA0D7FBF | 5/06/2022 | Sunday | Taneisha M | Delivery | No | 17 |
| A2E15BE0 | 5/06/2022 | Sunday | Gopinadh G | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 1A5FC1A6 | 6/06/2022 | Monday | Parikshit B | Delivery | Yes | 44 |
| 65CB2F73 | 6/06/2022 | Monday | Eric L | Delivery | Yes | 27 |
| F309B1B4 | 6/06/2022 | Monday | Yul K | Delivery | No | 41 |
| 5.16E+06 | 6/06/2022 | Monday | Liam B | Delivery | Yes | 21.5 |
| BE208273 | 6/06/2022 | Monday | Alexis S | Delivery | No | 34 |
| 13907A98 | 7/06/2022 | Tuesday | Bharun K | Delivery | No | 15 |
| BFBC1414 | 7/06/2022 | Tuesday | Beyonce R | Delivery | No | 16 |
| E1BEE521 | 7/06/2022 | Tuesday | Chris P | Pickup | No | 41.5 |
| 29CFA37C | 8/06/2022 | Wednesday | Mahesh S | Delivery | No | 39 |
| 861B4BF5 | 8/06/2022 | Wednesday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 21.5 |
| 402878D5 | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Patrick D | Delivery | Yes | 23.5 |
| D1FA7E6C | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Matthew C | Delivery | No | 13.5 |
| 67D46904 | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Manpreet S | Delivery | Yes | 25 |
| 2368CB72 | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Eric L | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 30CD8C73 | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Jason J | Delivery | No | 22 |
| 309446EC | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 23 |
| 29F86503 | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Saliha P | Delivery | No | 16 |
| 7AEECE7D | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Blaze H | Delivery | No | 28.5 |
| 8971D1AC | 9/06/2022 | Thursday | Simi K | Pickup | No | 14 |
| 8F2DF80B | 10/06/2022 | Friday | Henri U | Delivery | No | 75 |
| 7C43C605 | 11/06/2022 | Saturday | Moiz H | Delivery | Yes | 24.5 |
| 505550DF | 11/06/2022 | Saturday | Taylor M | Delivery | No | 14.5 |
| DA60DAD1 | 11/06/2022 | Saturday | Manpreet S | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 5ED98DE5 | 12/06/2022 | Sunday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 25 |
| CC26D3A9 | 12/06/2022 | Sunday | Jarra D | Delivery | No | 26.5 |
| C5DB4E4E | 12/06/2022 | Sunday | Nikki G | Delivery | Yes | 21.5 |
| 9582D832 | 12/06/2022 | Sunday | Tom H | Delivery | No | 32 |
| 1A659A5B | 12/06/2022 | Sunday | Catherine X | Delivery | Yes | 21 |
| 6AC5137B | 12/06/2022 | Sunday | Sara K | Delivery | Yes | 27 |
| 0ED93890 | 12/06/2022 | Sunday | Moiz H | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| DAE93BB3 | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Tayyab Y | Delivery | Yes | 22 |
| 12F34D56 | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Nikki C | Delivery | No | 4 |
| 62592433 | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Naveen K | Delivery | No | 18 |
| 4C29E93F | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Ashwin R | Delivery | Yes | 22.5 |
| FA377CC6 | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Elise S | Delivery | No | 17 |
| 4788B007 | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Justin P | Delivery | No | 18.5 |
| DF5E62EF | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Vishal M | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| 4CC5F072 | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Kate J | Delivery | Yes | 25 |
| 0D4CBED5 | 13/06/2022 | Monday | Andrew H | Delivery | No | 14 |
| 720B7B89 | 15/06/2022 | Wednesday | Kranthi B | Pickup | No | 25 |
| F1075B33 | 15/06/2022 | Wednesday | Seng L | Delivery | Yes | 22 |
| BB7128D7 | 15/06/2022 | Wednesday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 23.5 |
| 49F8E228 | 15/06/2022 | Wednesday | Atanu C | Delivery | Yes | 21 |
| 8D7C8862 | 15/06/2022 | Wednesday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 20.5 |
| B9BB1602 | 16/06/2022 | Thursday | Jaspal S | Pickup | No | 24 |
| 8F61F558 | 17/06/2022 | Friday | Gavin R | Delivery | No | 114.5 |
| DCC3BDFF | 17/06/2022 | Friday | Stephen K | Pickup | No | 37.5 |
| CC19A103 | 17/06/2022 | Friday | Shane B | Delivery | No | 31 |
| DB01FF68 | 18/06/2022 | Saturday | Nani C | Delivery | No | 21.5 |
| FEFA8B2D | 18/06/2022 | Saturday | Aman N | Delivery | Yes | 22 |
| 7D93989E | 18/06/2022 | Saturday | Yukthi P | Delivery | Yes | 41.5 |
| 32AEA598 | 18/06/2022 | Saturday | Joe V | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| 4DA4E399 | 18/06/2022 | Saturday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 15 |
| A117D85E | 18/06/2022 | Saturday | Sasha B | Delivery | No | 18 |
| C74A6FE6 | 18/06/2022 | Saturday | Gopinadh G | Delivery | Yes | 20.5 |
| D42C8282 | 19/06/2022 | Sunday | Ushan W | Delivery | No | 28 |
| 74D6C5F0 | 19/06/2022 | Sunday | Shagufta A | Delivery | Yes | 36 |
| A7C87962 | 19/06/2022 | Sunday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 70202A38 | 19/06/2022 | Sunday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 14.5 |
| D85AAFEC | 19/06/2022 | Sunday | Kranthi B | Pickup | No | 17 |
| 8CB59752 | 20/06/2022 | Monday | Revan N | Delivery | Yes | 23 |
| 011CB81F | 20/06/2022 | Monday | Anjana R | Delivery | Yes | 23 |
| DD1B126B | 21/06/2022 | Tuesday | Karishma N | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| AF0A8BD6 | 21/06/2022 | Tuesday | Manpreet S | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 58B04E2D | 21/06/2022 | Tuesday | Mukundan D | Delivery | Yes | 53 |
| 0C4D2881 | 21/06/2022 | Tuesday | Katherine G | Delivery | Yes | 26.5 |
| B2BDA0F5 | 21/06/2022 | Tuesday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 12 |
| 9BEE983E | 21/06/2022 | Tuesday | Barry S | Delivery | Yes | 26 |
| 2992A2C0 | 21/06/2022 | Tuesday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 23 |
| E89C39BC | 22/06/2022 | Wednesday | Revan N | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| C25B1E2A | 22/06/2022 | Wednesday | Sasha B | Delivery | No | 36 |
| 7301477C | 22/06/2022 | Wednesday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 13 |
| DFAA3DC9 | 23/06/2022 | Thursday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| 557B7EFE | 23/06/2022 | Thursday | Preety N | Delivery | Yes | 38 |
| 5D13D9FF | 23/06/2022 | Thursday | Asha D | Delivery | No | 18.5 |
| 762ECFE7 | 24/06/2022 | Friday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 21.5 |
| 266E6ED3 | 24/06/2022 | Friday | Kirby R | Delivery | Yes | 22.5 |
| 3745DA0F | 25/06/2022 | Saturday | Ullhas M | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| 93582AD8 | 25/06/2022 | Saturday | Taneisha M | Delivery | Yes | 49 |
| EB59DE04 | 25/06/2022 | Saturday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 12 |
| 92DD324C | 25/06/2022 | Saturday | Sara K | Delivery | Yes | 35.5 |
| 282982DA | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Ullhas M | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| C7E992B6 | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Lily B | Delivery | Yes | 30 |
| 8B58E8A5 | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Matthew B | Delivery | Yes | 42 |
| A9C62590 | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 4 |
| E89C18C3 | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 12 |
| C2B5A308 | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 20.25 |
| 66E30BD1 | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Uday B | Delivery | Yes | 25 |
| 5CFDDC6A | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Emily R | Delivery | No | 22 |
| 61B13EF0 | 26/06/2022 | Sunday | Matthew W | Delivery | No | 14 |
| 236C7D92 | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Nese K | Delivery | No | 12.5 |
| 9BC492AF | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Fiona G | Delivery | No | 18 |
| 9B43F8B5 | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Stuart D | Delivery | Yes | 30.5 |
| C23B6434 | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Sudheer M | Delivery | No | 21 |
| B8CFAB0E | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Jordana M | Delivery | Yes | 37 |
| D8713067 | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Emily R | Delivery | No | 39.5 |
| 5C14B208 | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Robert L | Delivery | Yes | 47 |
| 700C7B73 | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Mohit K | Pickup | No | 12 |
| 20BCBD1C | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Sudheer M | Delivery | Yes | 21 |
| BE7A5725 | 27/06/2022 | Monday | Jade G | Delivery | No | 27 |
| 370EEF0E | 28/06/2022 | Tuesday | Mayur K | Delivery | No | 21 |
| 7871A3CF | 28/06/2022 | Tuesday | David L | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| E900945C | 28/06/2022 | Tuesday | Sharon L | Delivery | No | 6 |
| 756D822C | 28/06/2022 | Tuesday | Jeevan K | Delivery | Yes | 33 |
| 9340F715 | 28/06/2022 | Tuesday | Jabba M | Delivery | Yes | 22.5 |
| B0D5279F | 28/06/2022 | Tuesday | Sharon L | Delivery | Yes | 36 |
| 809ACE9A | 28/06/2022 | Tuesday | Stacey G | Delivery | Yes | 26 |
| 2E3D9203 | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Sarah S | Delivery | Yes | 23 |
| CEEC142C | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Revan N | Delivery | Yes | 23 |
| 163D3019 | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Uday D | Delivery | No | 19.5 |
| 4A6F2910 | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Ahmad N | Pickup | No | 14 |
| 171B0930 | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Cherry C | Delivery | Yes | 20.5 |
| 4548E49B | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Sudheer M | Delivery | Yes | 23.25 |
| 3B6B95EE | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Lili M | Delivery | Yes | 30.5 |
| 793E5624 | 29/06/2022 | Wednesday | Sanjuna R | Delivery | Yes | 25 |
| 366C776E | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Joshua B | Delivery | No | 24.5 |
| 136CBFA9 | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Arshnoor K | Delivery | Yes | 32 |
| 5C1A3A50 | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Jordana M | Delivery | Yes | 22 |
| 8CF70080 | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Emily R | Delivery | No | 37 |
| 0378646A | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | James B | Delivery | Yes | 37.5 |
| AE5D1140 | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Priyanka J | Delivery | Yes | 22.5 |
| 3DFAF32D | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Barry L | Delivery | Yes | 20.5 |
| E3BB71AA | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 606A8651 | 30/06/2022 | Thursday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 23 |
| DA677B0B | 1/07/2022 | Friday | Clara D | Delivery | No | 28 |
| E8466E3B | 1/07/2022 | Friday | Pappu S | Pickup | No | 2 |
| 5115E617 | 1/07/2022 | Friday | Denise S | Delivery | Yes | 75.5 |
| DB1D9E0A | 1/07/2022 | Friday | Shrikant B | Delivery | No | 24 |
| AB80281C | 1/07/2022 | Friday | Matthew P | Delivery | No | 19.5 |
| B8C35E3B | 1/07/2022 | Friday | Christine J | Delivery | No | 15 |
| 638E4895 | 2/07/2022 | Saturday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 23A869BE | 2/07/2022 | Saturday | Sarah S | Delivery | Yes | 26.5 |
| 791A3048 | 2/07/2022 | Saturday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 12 |
| 5DABEC88 | 2/07/2022 | Saturday | Jeni B | Delivery | No | 40.5 |
| AB39A329 | 2/07/2022 | Saturday | Sharon L | Delivery | Yes | 44.5 |
| 541684 | 2/07/2022 | Saturday | Anu E | Delivery | No | 13.5 |
| BEA2A69A | 2/07/2022 | Saturday | Uday B | Delivery | Yes | 24.5 |
| 7F5FC07D | 3/07/2022 | Sunday | Patrick D | Delivery | Yes | 26 |
| 57860FA3 | 3/07/2022 | Sunday | Shaiyan A | Delivery | Yes | 15 |
| EE5A443C | 3/07/2022 | Sunday | Eleanor R M | Delivery | No | 44.5 |
| D14F4CBA | 3/07/2022 | Sunday | Chris P | Pickup | No | 20 |
| BE024751 | 3/07/2022 | Sunday | Krishna S | Delivery | Yes | 27 |
| 94C86B9B | 3/07/2022 | Sunday | Cherry C | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 54F294CC | 4/07/2022 | Monday | Saranya G | Delivery | Yes | 24 |
| C85488DD | 4/07/2022 | Monday | Daniel M | Delivery | Yes | 47.5 |
| BE44EEA7 | 4/07/2022 | Monday | Anjesh S | Delivery | No | 13 |
| 7A3D7E3C | 4/07/2022 | Monday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 12 |
| 0559FC10 | 4/07/2022 | Monday | Jordana M | Delivery | Yes | 55 |
| 0181D585 | 5/07/2022 | Tuesday | Vamsi K | Delivery | No | 24 |
| D4DFE2C3 | 5/07/2022 | Tuesday | Rafael V | Delivery | No | 15.5 |
| 59E66723 | 5/07/2022 | Tuesday | Revan N | Delivery | Yes | 20 |
| 0761D2C6 | 5/07/2022 | Tuesday | Asif M | Delivery | Yes | 20.5 |
| 2DE7C9CC | 5/07/2022 | Tuesday | Mathew W | Pickup | No | 24.5 |
| A30F0501 | 5/07/2022 | Tuesday | Allison R | Delivery | Yes | 26.5 |
| EB35D8EC | 6/07/2022 | Wednesday | Vishal P | Delivery | No | 16.5 |
| 2013A564 | 6/07/2022 | Wednesday | Sarah S | Delivery | Yes | 28.5 |
| C546702E | 6/07/2022 | Wednesday | Tj J | Delivery | Yes | 20.5 |
| 79CC94A0 | 6/07/2022 | Wednesday | Shane B | Delivery | No | 22 |
| 1FBE376F | 6/07/2022 | Wednesday | D H | Delivery | No | 27 |
| 8211753A | 7/07/2022 | Thursday | Louise L | Pickup | No | 36 |
| 6B3AEA38 | 7/07/2022 | Thursday | Trishla | Delivery | No | 13 |
| 46CF8E78 | 7/07/2022 | Thursday | Marie S | Delivery | No | 31.5 |
| 2ABCD55B | 9/07/2022 | Saturday | Jason D | Delivery | Yes | 21 |
| 21728640 | 9/07/2022 | Saturday | Mayank D | Delivery | Yes | 25 |
| B906D26A | 9/07/2022 | Saturday | Matthew P | Delivery | No | 26.5 |
| 7205A108 | 10/07/2022 | Sunday | Yunjin P | Delivery | No | 32.5 |
| 812B04D7 | 10/07/2022 | Sunday | Sudheer M | Delivery | Yes | 22 |
| E7F83AB8 | 11/07/2022 | Monday | Simon P | Delivery | Yes | 29 |
| 6B554017 | 11/07/2022 | Monday | Chaudhari M | Delivery | Yes | 27 |
| 24B6E713 | 11/07/2022 | Monday | Asif M | Delivery | Yes | 21 |
| 773BC15C | 11/07/2022 | Monday | Emily R | Delivery | No | 41 |
| A307D461 | 11/07/2022 | Monday | Sudheer M | Delivery | Yes | 20.5 |
| C0AB1F14 | 12/07/2022 | Tuesday | Chaudhari M | Delivery | Yes | 41.25 |
| AF0564CF | 12/07/2022 | Tuesday | Lee M | Delivery | Yes | 48.5 |

Comment: What you posted isn't a valid SQL statement and doesn't even calculate a count. Post a proper query that reproduces what you claim. SQL isn't wrong. Either the data isn't what you assumed or the way you calculate counts in Excel or Tableau is different.

Comment: BTW, it's naive to use a personal `Name` column as a key-value for your rows. Don't you have a true primary-key (well, foreign-key) for People?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type -few databases do.  `Bit` is often used for this with `1` meaning True. Post a sample `CREATE TABLE` clause, sample data and a query that reproduces the problem

Comment: A fiddle would be great, so we can see the difference. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019 can be used.

Comment: Remove one row at the time and see when you get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

````
select IsDashpass,count(*) as NbCustomers from
(select 
    t.NAME,IsDashpass=(case when Nb>0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) 
from 
    (select NAME,sum(case when Dashpass='No' then 0 else 1 end) as Nb from dd_customers group by NAME) t
) t2
group by t2.IsDashpass```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I remove Distinct, won't it count all the "yes" in the data? I only want to see how many customers were a "yes" or "no".

Comment: I changed the query, try this new one.

Comment: Thanks, but still getting 87 for "no" and 104 for "yes". I might not be explaining clearly. I'll try again.

Comment: Thanks, but still getting 87 for "no" and 104 for "yes". I might not be explaining clearly. I'll try again.

I want to see how many customers were dashpass members or not. Dashpass member ='yes', non-dashpass member ='no'. There are certain customers who ordered more than once here such as "Priyanka J", but they should be only counted as one. Your query counts every record of Priyanka J, but she should only be counted once. Hence, I used distinct to remove more than one instance of a name

Comment: I updated the query can you give it a try ?

Comment: 62 for No and 66 for yes. Unfortunately we're still not getting the right answer.